# How do I get left-aligned output from text-mode Maple?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface, maple, output-formatting

The file `a.ms` contains:

```
A:=6:
A*7;
```

When I run

```
maple -q a.ms
```

I get:

```
                                      42
(empty line)
```

I want to get:

```
42
```

That is, `42` should be left-aligned, and no empty line after it.

How do I get that?

I'm looking for an answer which proposes a Maple-only solution without the need additional filtering.

Comment: If it is always a number, you can just pipe to `grep -o '[0-9]*'`. But not sure if it is the case, neither if `maple` has some way to handle this.

Comment: I'm looking for an answer which proposes a Maple-only solution without the need additional filtering. Updated the question.

Comment: How about using Maple's `printf` command.

Comment: It won't format nicely, but there is also the command interface(prettyprint=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following acer's comments, this did the trick:

```
A:=6:
printf("%d\n", A*7):
```

This also did the trick:

```
interface(prettyprint=0):
A:=6:
A*7;
```